# How do I correctly import Bootstrap using sass and use variables across different files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have the following project structure:

```
/resources
  /components
    component-a.js
    component-a.html
    component-a.scss
  /scss
    bootstrap.scss
    variables.scss
my-app.js
my-app.html
my-app.scss
```

I am using the [aurelia framework](https://docs.aurelia.io/), but I don't think that makes much of a difference here.

I am also using webpack, with these loaders `style-loader, cssLoader, postcssLoader, sassLoader`. Hence, my webpack config looks like this:

```
rules: [
...
{ test: /\.scss$/i, use: [ 'style-loader', cssLoader, postcssLoader, sassLoader ] },
...
]
```

My `bootstrap.scss` file looks like this (I know that `@import` is deprecated, but it's the only way to get bootstrap to work here):

```
// https: //getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets (including any separate color mode stylesheets)
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";

// 4. Include any default map overrides here

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/root";

// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
...

// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// 8. Add additional custom code here
```

Now my `my-app.scss` file looks like this. This is the first scss file that is imported and brings in all of bootstrap.

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use './resources/scss/variables' as v;
@use './resources/scss/bootstrap';

...
```

This all works up to here. Now here is my problem:

I would like to have access to some of the bootstrap variables/classes in `component-a.scss`. If I try to use `@use ./resources/scss/bootstrap` the whole bootstrap code is included in the css output. Meaning that it's now imported twice.

I can verify this be taking a look at the style tags using dev tools.

`component-a.scss`

```
@use ./resources/scss/bootstrap; //imports everything
@forward ./resources/scss/bootstrap; //imports everything

...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.

```
/scss
    bootstrap.scss
    variables.scss
```

`variables.scss`

```
// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here
$border-color: #85bdde;

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets (including any separate color mode stylesheets)
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";

// 4. Include any default map overrides here

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

`bootstrap.scss`

```
@use './variables' as *;

@import "bootstrap/scss/root";

// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/scss/accordion";
@import "bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "bootstrap/scss/spinners";
@import "bootstrap/scss/offcanvas";
@import "bootstrap/scss/placeholders";
@import "bootstrap/scss/forms";

@import "bootstrap/scss/helpers";

// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// 8. Add additional custom code here
```

In my `main.js` file I have this at the very top to ensure that bs is loaded first.

```
import './resources/scss/bootstrap.scss'
```

Now, if I need access to a variable in any other `scss` file all I have to do is

```
@use './variables' as *; // or whatever namespace you want
```